# Rails 3: Soap4r returning "Assert: unknown array definition" for akamai request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, soap, soap4r, akamai

Upgrading some things in our app, and now our soap requests to Akamai aren't firing.  Unit tests instead cause a return of `RuntimeError: Assert: unknown array definition`

Here's the akamai class:

```
require 'rexml/document'

class Akamai
  def self.purge_cache(url)
    require 'soap/wsdlDriver'
    factory = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new('https://ccuapi.akamai.com/ccuapi-axis.wsdl')
    driver = factory.create_rpc_driver
    driver.purgeRequest(
      'our-username', # username
      'our-password', # password
      '', # network; deprecated
      [], # options
      [url]
      )
  end
end
```

I thought it might be some new gems I've added onto our upgraded branch, but there are only two additions to the Gemfile:

```
gem 'libxml-ruby', '1.1.4'
gem 'nokogiri'
```

Removing them doesn't fix the problem though.  Here's the error spew:

```
test_unsuccessful_purge(AkamaiTest):
RuntimeError: Assert: Unknown array definition.
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/wsdl/soap/complexType.rb:122:in `find_arytype'
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/wsdl/soap/complexType.rb:161:in `content_arytype'
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/wsdl/soap/complexType.rb:55:in `child_type'
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/soap/mapping/wsdlencodedregistry.rb:168:in `array2soap'
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/soap/mapping/wsdlencodedregistry.rb:145:in `complexobj2soap'
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/soap/mapping/wsdlencodedregistry.rb:121:in `obj2typesoap'
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/soap/mapping/wsdlencodedregistry.rb:38:in `obj2soap'
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/soap/mapping/mapping.rb:135:in `_obj2soap'
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/soap/mapping/mapping.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in objs2soap'
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/soap/mapping/mapping.rb:52:in `upto'
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/soap/mapping/mapping.rb:52:in `block in objs2soap'
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/soap/mapping/mapping.rb:560:in `block in protect_mapping'
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/soap/mapping/mapping.rb:533:in `protect_threadvars'
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/soap/mapping/mapping.rb:549:in `protect_mapping'
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/soap/mapping/mapping.rb:51:in `objs2soap'
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/soap/rpc/proxy.rb:475:in `request_rpc_enc'
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/soap/rpc/proxy.rb:457:in `request_rpc'
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/soap/rpc/proxy.rb:412:in `request_body'
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/soap/rpc/proxy.rb:127:in `call'
    /Users/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@media3/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9-2.0.3/lib/soap/rpc/driver.rb:151:in `call'
    (eval):6:in `purgeRequest'
    /Users/kevin/code/medialytics/app/models/akamai.rb:8:in `purge_cache'
    test/unit/akamai_test.rb:12:in `block in <class:AkamaiTest>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up dumping soap4r-ruby1.9 all together and going with Savon, since it's been updated more recently and seems to be better put-together.